# Can you trigger a specific exit status on a php fatal error?

Tags: php, bash

I've tried the following:

```
<?php
function shutdown_find_exit()
{
    exit(50);
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown_find_exit');

trigger_error("Fatal error", E_USER_ERROR);

?>
```

But that still exists with an error code of 255.

I'm trying to have an error code of 50 returned.

I'm checking it with the following bash script:

```
php tester.php
status=$?
echo Exit Code: ${status}
```

Updated code based on the accepted answer for anyone interested:

```
<?php
function shutdown_find_exit()
{
    exit('50');
}
register_shutdown_function('shutdown_find_exit');

trigger_error("Fatal error", E_USER_ERROR);
?>
```

and the bash script

```
output="$(php tester.php)"
status=$?
echo Exit Code: ${status}
if [[ $output == *"50"* ]]
then
  echo "Got 50";
fi
```

Comment: Calling the shutdown functions is just the first of a dozen things PHP does on script termination/exit. Which is why the shutdown callbacks can't override the exit code anymore I'd guess. (Btw, `70` would be a better result code, `EX_SOFTWARE`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **TL;DR:** use a string, instead of an int.

[php `exit( status )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php)

> If status is a string, this function prints the status just
>   before exiting.
>
> If status is an integer, that value will be used as the exit status
>   and not printed. Exit statuses should be in the range 0 to 254, the
>   exit status 255 is reserved by PHP and shall not be used. The status 0
>   is used to terminate the program successfully.

**Note: PHP >= 4.2.0 does NOT print the status if it is an integer.**

## Execute php script in bash, assign output to variable.

```
variable = $(/path/to/php -f $HOME/path/to/my.php)
```

For example:

```
# just executing php, but capturing output then, prints it to console
status = $(/usr/bin/php -f $HOME/path/to/tester.php)
echo Exit Code: ${status}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I use a string, that string is displayed, but the exit code captured by the bash script is still 255.

Comment: @Rob: i've updated with an example maybe useful to you.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I updated the original question showing the code I used.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing.. pay it forward :)

Answer (score 1):

See if this does what you want to do:

```
trigger_error("Fatal error", shutdown_find_exit());
```

Comment: This actually did work, but I was just using the trigger_error as an easy way to trigger the error to make the example shorter.  I apperciate the effort, but I'm going to mark Adrian's because that answer worked better for me.